# how to render DT::datatables in a pdf using rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, datatable, r-markdown, dt

How can I display `DT::datatable` objects from a `rmarkdown` script onto a pdf document? My code so far is breaks down with the following error:

```
processing file: reportCopy.Rmd
output file: reportCopy.knit.md
Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
```

Including `always_allow_html: yes` in the YAML header  suppresses the error, but nothing appears on the pdf.

I would be grateful for any help. My code is currently:

````
---
title: "DT"
output: pdf_document
---

### Chart 1
```{r}
DT::datatable(head(mtcars))
```
````

( I don't know if it matters, but my datatables are in fact created in a `shiny` application. Ideally, I would have liked to have the prerendered tables simply dumped into the `rmarkdown` script... but I switched tactic and now try to render the tables directly in the `rmarkdown` code)

Comment: If you're flexible on who's rendering the table, there are [other table options](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-7.html) for R Markdown like `knitr::kable`.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer Thanks for this answer. I think I might indeed have to switch to kable.. but I would rather do otherwise because the entire codebase (which comes from a Shiny app) is written using DT::datatables.

Comment: you cannot use` datatable` in `pdf_document` (`datatable` is interactive), only in `html_document`! the only possibility for PDF is to use the `kable` or for example `pandoc.table`

Comment: @Malvina_a Thanks for this comment.... this is what I feared most. If you are sure, please do not hesitate to put is as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since knitr v1.13, HTML widgets will be rendered automatically as screenshots taken via the webshot package.

You need to install the webshot package and PhantomJS:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

(see https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to execute that second line of code (I raised the issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563874/r-webshotinstall-phantomjs-error-403 but it has not been answered). But I am happy to know that a solution to the initial problem exists!

Comment: `````````` '''{r chunklabel, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
if(is.null(webshot:::find_phantom())){webshot::install_phantomjs()}
DT::datatable(iris)

'''   ``````````

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use`datatable` in `pdf_document` (`datatable` is interactive, pdf is static), only in html_document! 
The only possibility for PDF is to use the `kable` or for example `pandoc.table`

**-->** if You really wanna get the look of `datatable` and as You said `datatable` is created in a `shiny` application, then You can have a look at the `webshot` package, which is going to create a screenshot of Your `datatable` from `shiny` app which You can use further in pdf as a image.