# render DT::datatables in a pdf using rmarkdown?

Tags: datatable, datatables, r-markdown

This is similar to [how to render DT::datatables in a pdf using rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543858/how-to-render-dtdatatables-in-a-pdf-using-rmarkdown)

DataTable has an option to add a pdf button and export and nice looking pdf of the Table. (see https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html)

Is there a way to do this in Rmarkdown directly? It would save me effort of converting a list of DTs to kable.