# knit datatable format created in r into pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, dt

I am producing an **R-markdown** report where plots and data tables are knitted into a **pdf**.

These data tables (package DT) have fantastic formatting options like styleColorBar, which I can see from the Viewer, in an HTML when I print in that format, but not in pdf, as far as I tried. 
Here is a sample of my code, where the second column, dist, should have intensity-bars in the cell background.

```
---
title: "prove27_2"
author: "Roberto Di Pietro"
date: "27/2/2020"
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(DT)
colors<-viridis::viridis(3,alpha=.3)[1]
datatable(cars) %>% formatStyle(names(cars)[2],
                                            background = styleColorBar(range(cars[,2]),
                                                                       colors
                                            ),
                                            backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                                            backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                                            backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Is it something possible? Does it have to do with js or css or simply with an option that I am missing to find?

Comment: Your color is in hex format `"#RRGGBBAA"` It seems that doesn't work for such a format. Try `"rgba(68,1,84,0.3)"` instead. I tried and there is the color in the pdf but the result is weird. Also note that you need the [`webshot` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545374/1100107).

Comment: Thank you, Stephane, I do have the package `webshot`.
As for the format, I replaced "colors" at line 5 with a simple "lightblue", which should be indeed in rgba format and I do get the colours in PDF! But,  they do look weird (what's white is now deep black and alpha looks like is stuck at 1).

Comment: Yes I also got the black. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your color is in hex format `"#RRGGBBAA"` It seems that doesn't work for such a format (even outside Rmarkdown). You can use `"rgba(68,1,84,0.3)"` instead.

But in order to have a correct rendering with a PDF Rmarkdown document, there is something else to do. By default, a htmlwidget in a PDF Rmarkdown document is converted to a PDF figure with `webshot::webshot`. But sometimes there are certain HTML elements that fail to render to the PDF screenshot. Use the chunk option `dev='png'` to get a PNG screenshot, which works better.

````
---
title: "prove27_2"
author: "Roberto Di Pietro"
date: "27/2/2020"
output: pdf_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r, dev='png'}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DT)
datatable(cars) %>% 
  formatStyle(names(cars)[2],
              background = styleColorBar(range(cars[,2]), "rgba(68,1,84,0.3)"),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```
````